# Download image from Mysql with url to custom listview

Tags: java, android, mysql

I want to make Custom Listview on android. I downloaded one image from Mysql but ı Can Not downloaded second image in one post. The error is : `E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3.`

My downloader codes ;

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
```

I calling with this code ;

```
 new DownloadImageTask((ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView)).execute(photo);
```

Comment: why is this tagged php?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Glide instead if you have the option, you will avoid the headache of synchronization and can easily handle the errors:
add this to your dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

and then you can load the images with:

```
 Glide.with(this).load(url).into(imageView);
```

source:
https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: I added this library but a new error : Can not resolve method(com.example.emrah.hıomework.CustomAdapter)

Comment: Glide.with(this).load(profilpicture).into(profileimage); cannot accept "this"